# Locating project templates in ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-pro, template

Does anyone know where the blank, global, scene and map aptx files in ArcGIS Pro are stored?

I notice that any project settings that you change, persist. I'm trying to get my blank.aptx to go back to what it looked like the first time I used it.

Answer (score 0):

C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ProjectTemplates

Comment: Does anyone know where is blank located then?